# How did Natsu solve his transportation problem?

Tags: fairy-tail

In chapter 425, Natsu is seen riding a boar. How come his motion sickness had not kicked in?

> [image: Natsu riding a boar with Lucy]

He should've built an immunity to Wendy's anti-motion-sickness spell, so why isn't he getting a motion sickness here?

Comment: main reason is distraction, he is distracted with many thing , one is Gray, he does not get motion sickness riding animal if he does not think it as transportation medium.

Answer (score 4):

The same as Happy applies. The boar is not a transportation vehicle, it's a living creature.

Comment: The reason why Natsu is not getting a motion sickness from Happy is not because Happy is a living creature. It's because Happy is his friend. If it is because its a living creature, then he won't get a motion sickness from Fukurou.

Comment: This was actually Natsu's own answer when Lucy confronted him of how he's not sick when flying with Happy. "Because Happy is Happy, and not a vehicle".

Comment: I'd forgotten about that one. Well I guess it could be explained by the rockets http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/fairytail/images/c/c8/Fukuro_grabs_Natsu_by_the_leg.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110601192300. It's a mechanical way to fly so I guess the argument holds (kinda).

Comment: @DaMachk I thought that line was in relationship to something that Lucy was doing at the time and was a way of poking fun at her. It has been a while since I read the series so can't say for sure.

Comment: @JoeW don't overthink shonen manga/anime :D not everything is logical, not everything is explainable... and probably not even the author knows why he did it the way they did it back then anymore :D

Comment: @DaMachk How is it overthinking to have a memory that mentioning Happy didn't count as transport because it is happy and it was brought up as something that Lucy was currently involved in and became a joke?

Answer (score -1):

Natsu gets motion sickness when he is riding a vehicle but he does not get motion sickness riding animals.(Well Natsu is an animal XD)